# Center one html element among a variable number of other html elements

Tags: center, html

I've got a dynamic menu containing span elements. In my script i'm able to update this menu, and therefore this menu can contain more/less of these span elements. These span elements contain pagetitles, also with variable length of characters. All of these spans are aligned horizontaly.

What i'm trying to do is center all these spans (this is easy) But i need one span to be always in the middle among the variable number of spans. This span will be used as an empty spacer.

Why? Well it's a design i'm working on. The middle of this menu is overlapped by an image, and therefore overlapping the spans. With the "always centered span", i'm trying to create a spacer in the menu so none of the spans would be behind this image.

The html so far:

```
<div class = 'header'>
    <div class = 'header_image'>
        <img src = 'centerd_image.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class = 'header_menu'>
        <span>the empty spacer</span>
        <span>menu1</span>
        <span>menu2</span>
        <span>menu3</span>
        <span>menu4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css so far:

```
.header{
background-color: #90a9c4;
border-bottom: solid #728eac 25px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
height: 46px;
}

.header_image{
width: 123px;
height: 89px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -61px;
z-index: 3;
}

.header_menu {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

How can i get

```
<span>the empty spacer</span>
```

to be always in the middle of these 4 (or more!)

```
<span>menu1</span>
<span>menu2</span>
<span>menu3</span>
<span>menu4</span>
```

Comment: are these going to be in a list? and do you want the space to be between them? for that you can just use padding... they just appear in a line on my test

Comment: Should have added some more info about that, the spans will be aligned horizontaly, and only the "empty spacer span" should be in the middle, the rest should automaticly be left & right from the centered "empty spacer span"

Comment: you could set the position to width/2 absolute?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The spans have auto width & the menu does so too

Comment: hmm i was thinking you could reposition it to the menu width/2 after adding stuff to it... in your script. shouldn't matter that your width is auto it should return a value anyway.

Comment: you should really create a new class for your empty spacer span and define it in the css display:inline; text-align:center; and put a &nbsp into it